# Django 1.9 read value from request.POST

Tags: python, django, django-1.9

So I'm trying to make a script that would ask users a few questions and based on the answers they have chosen, perform an action. 
I'm very new to Django so I'm still not sure on how it fully works and so I'm basing my code off the tutorial found on their website (until I get a better understanding)
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/

models.py

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Option(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    option_text = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.option_text
```

views.py

```
def select(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_option = question.option_set.get(pk=request.POST['option'])
    except (KeyError, Option.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'awsservers/detail.html', {
        'question':question,
        'error_message': "You did not select an option.",
        })
    if selected_option:
        # run code here
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('awsservers:extra', args=(question.id,)))
```

detail.html

```
<h2>{{ question.question_text }}</h2>

<form action="{% url 'awsservers:select' question.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for option in question.option_set.all %}
    <input type = "radio" name = "option" id = "option{{ forloop.counter }}"  value = "{{ option.id }}" />
    <label for = "option{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ option.option_text }}</label><br />
{% endfor %}
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Select" />
</form>

<a href="{% url 'awsservers:index' %}">Go Back</a>
```

I'm stuck at views.py code. I would like to read the selected_option value so I can run the required action based on what is selected.

```
if selected_option == 'value':
    perform action
elif selected_option == 'value2':
    perform other action
```

Comment: I do not understand what errors you are facing. Can't you just use `selected_option`? or `selected_option.option_text`

Comment: sorry if i haven't explained the question properly. 
to my understanding - when a user selects an option, it gets stored in "selected_option". I'm trying to read what option they have selected and I'm also not sure in what format it is being stored in "selected_option" but looking at the html code, it seems like the option id is being stored in the variable so I would like to read the variable and check if the user has selected option 1 then perform an action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, `selected_option` is an object, so using `if selected_option == 'value'` is not very useful. On the other hand, you can compare `selected_option`'s attributes to arbitrary things such as numbers and strings, for example:

```
if selected_option.id == 1: return True  # Will return True if the option chosen has an ID of 1
```

OR

```
if selected_option.option_text == 'SOME OPTION TEXT': return True  # Will return True if the option chosen matches the option text I compared it to
```